# How to get data from content script 1 to add-on script to content script 2?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm afraid I haven't figured out how the communication between scripts via `port` works.
Within `panel.js` I listen for a submit button to be pressed in the panel. I save values in an array `vals` and pass them with:

```
self.port.emit("submitted", vals);
```

listen in `main.js` with:

```
panel.port.on("submitted", function(vals) { ... });
```

and now I would like to send `vals` to another content script ('page.js') which will use the data in order to manipulate the DOM of a site.

On main.js I tried:

```
require("page-mod").PageMod({
    include: "*",
    contentScriptWhen: 'end',
    contentScriptFile: data.url("page.js"),
    onAttach: function(worker) {
        panel.on('submitted', function(vals) {
            worker.port.emit('output', vals);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, what you are trying looks like it would work - only that you probably want to replace `panel.on` by `panel.port.on`. However, workers can come and go, you don't want to attempt communicating with the ones no longer there. The [documentation](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.8/packages/addon-kit/page-mod.html) has a nice example allowing to keep track of active workers, it can be slightly adjusted for your purposes:

```js
var workers = [];

var pageMod = require("page-mod").PageMod({
  include: '*',
  contentScriptWhen: 'end',
  contentScriptFile: data.url('page.js'),
  onAttach: function(worker) {
    // Add new worker to the list
    workers.push(worker);
    worker.on('detach', function () {
      // Remove no longer active worker from the list
      var index = workers.indexOf(worker);
      if (index >= 0)
        workers.splice(index, 1);
    });
  }
});

panel.port.on('submitted', function(vals) {
  for (var i = 0; i < workers.length; i++)
    workers[i].port.emit('output', vals);
});
```